# How to be able to edit field in Django admin panel

Tags: python, django

I do not see edit icon in django admin panel in the detail page of my model. It looks like this:

[image]

Thus normally it should have `add icon` and `edit icon`, something like this:
[image]

But the edit icon is missing.

My model is as follows:

```
class BusinessUnit(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    brands = models.ManyToManyField(to=Brand)
    site_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=settings.MEDIA_ROOT, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.ForeignKey(to=Address)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

And in admin.py i have the code as follows:

```
class BusinessUnitAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ('name',)
    list_display = ('name', 'address', )

admin.site.register(BusinessUnit, BusinessUnitAdmin)
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: do you have another model that shows the Edit Icon? Try removing the (to=) from the ForeignKey....usually I go with ForeignKey(Address)

Comment: @Walucas Actually no. All my models show only the Add icon. I tried to remove `to` but the same problem.

Comment: whats your Django version?

Comment: @Walucas Django==1.4.22

Comment: You are using a very old version, I am not sure that this version has this feature!

Comment: @Walucas Yes I know. But the whole project is done in that version and I cannot update it.

Comment: I'm not sure that it would even make sense to have edit icon next to the "Brands" field? What would edit mean if you selected none of the options, or if you selected more than 1?

Comment: @bonidjukic Brands are not important. I need to be able to edit address.

Answer (score 0):

According to this Ticket: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13165, this was delivered on Django 1.8